# Cannot allocate memory error in nginx with huge number of redirections

Tags: nginx, memory-management

I faced with memory allocation error in nginx. I have configured reverse proxy for a number of sites on my nginx, that I use as simple load balancer between two backend nodes. Typical config for site looks like this:

```
upstream backend  {
  ip_hash;
  server <node-ip>;
  server <another-node-ip>;
}

server {
  server_name domain.subdomain.com;    

  # a HUGE bunch of redirection rules 
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/root;

  location / {

    proxy_pass  http://backend  ;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

I have 12 sites with configuration like above. As you see config contains `include` of another file - `sites-available/root`. This file consists of a number of `unclude` directives to another files:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules1;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules2;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules3;
...
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/rules16;
```

Every rules file contains a number of redirection rules like:

```
if ($request_uri ~* ^/some-url$) {
  return 302 /some-another-url/;
}
```

or

```
location ~ some-url {
  return 302 "some-another-url";
}
```

The total count of redirection rules is around 2300. I included `root` file to configurations of all 12 sites. After that time after time I get info message in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

> [info] 23721#23721: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66

The main problem is that sometimes command `service nginx reload` fails with errors in log:

> [alert] 22164#22164: fork() failed while spawning "worker process" (12: Cannot allocate memory)
>   2018/10/09 03:10:06
>
> [alert] 22164#22164: sendmsg() failed (9: Bad file descriptor)

The issue is gone, if I exclude redirection rules from config. Nginx is set up on simple AWS t2.small instance with Ubuntu 16.04. It has 1GB of RAM and I see (with `free -m`) that at least half of the memory is free. I have default nginx.conf. So the question is how to avoid `cannot allocate memory` error, that is caused by huge number of redirection rules?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in fact with "push" module. It is third party. I would recommend to re-build Nginx without it and see what happens.

Comment: Cold you say what exactly module should be removed? I set up nginx on ubuntu via apt-get. I see this `add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-http-push` in apt-get configuration. Also I found this module - https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/push_stream/.

Comment: Try installing an official Nginx build from [their repository](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem but i had another param added for caching

```
 proxy_cache_path /Users/xx/nginx/cache keys_zone=mycache:1000m;
```

but i was using a t2 micro so it didnt have that much memory so it was causing the error i changed it to 5m and started the nginx server again it worked